# Store function to indexed arrays and call him with undefault param

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to create and indexed array of functions to call him with changed params, like this:

```
local function wubba(lubba)
    return lubba
end

local dub = {
    ["wubba"] = {func = wubba(lubba)}
}

print(dub["wubba"].func("hi"))
```

But in all my tries i got errors, i can't figure out how to do it. Anyone can help me?

```
lua: wubba.lua:9: attempt to call field 'func' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    wubba.lua:9: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, just not to store with params:

```
local dub = {
    ["wubba"] = {func = wubba}
}
```

Comment: Or just properly define the function in the table